# Duplicate bar chart from Excell into an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I'm having a very rough time trying to group this SSRS chart correctly.  It's easy as pie in Excel.  So I'm wondering what I need to do in SSRS to duplicate it.

There are no hard errors to report other than the data is not being displayed the way I want it to be displayed.

One image shows the Chart Data I am passing into the chart, the other shows the visual appearance.

The final image is taken from Excell and shows what I am trying to do inside SSRS.  The Excel chart displays it just about perfectly to what I am looking for.

[image]

[image]

The next two images are from excell.  One displays just about perfectly how I am trying to get it to look on SSRS.  The other one is how I am passing the data into SSRS.

[image]

[image]

Any idea how I need to group the data within the SSRS chart to display it the way I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you can create the exact copy of that graph, but
try making the graph larger (taller) and also change vertical axis interval to 1
(right click on vertical axis go into properties>> axis options >> interval 1)
you can get something like this

[image]